# In terraform, how do I use a passed-in variable for a map?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform v0.12.3

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.3
+ provider.aws v2.20.0
```

I have this map variable in my variables.tf file

```
variable "subnet_id" {
  type = map
  description = "Subnet to use"
  default = {
    sandbox = {
      us-east-1a = "subnet-1234"
      us-east-1b = "subnet-2345"
      us-east-1c = "subnet-3456"
      us-east-1d = ""
      us-east-1e = ""
      us-east-1f = ""
    }
    staging = {
      us-east-1a = "subnet-4567"
      us-east-1b = "subnet-5678"
      us-east-1c = "subnet-6789"
      us-east-1d = ""
      us-east-1e = ""
      us-east-1f = ""
    }
    production = {
      us-east-1a = "subnet-7890"
      us-east-1b = "subnet-0987"
      us-east-1c = "subnet-9876"
      us-east-1d = "subnet-8765"
      us-east-1e = "subnet-7654"
      us-east-1f = ""
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the subnet id that I want by passing an environment variable? IOW, I want to...

```
$ terraform plan -var 'environment=sandbox'
```

and in my main.tf code I have

```
module "jenkins_slave" {
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id[var.environment["us-east-1a"]]
  ....
}
```

I get

```
$ terraform plan -var environment="sandbox"
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 17, in module "jenkins-slaves":
  17:   subnet_id         = var.subnet_id[var.environment["us-east-1a"]]
    |----------------
    | var.environment is "sandbox"

This value does not have any indices.
```

In my case, I want `subnet_id` key to ultimately be equal to `subnet-1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to be able to pass a variable, you need to define it in your code:

```
variable "environment" {}
```

Besides, instead of `var.subnet_id[var.environment["us-east-1a"]]` you need to have `var.subnet_id[var.environment]["us-east-1a"]`.

Otherwise, `var.environment["us-east-1a"]` is referring to `us-east-1a` key of `environment` map. In your case `environment` is just a string not a map, thus Terraform is throwing an error: `This value does not have any indices.`.

P.S. Seems, you also have a typo in the `variable "subnet_id" {...}`, `ssandbox` should be `sandbox`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I actually tried the correct syntax you gave, but the typo was more than likely the problem. I fixed the original post.